# Flask App not calling Babel localeselector

Tags: python, flask, gettext, python-babel, flask-babel

I am adding localisation to my Flask app with Flask-Babel, and I cannot seem to change the language.  I followed all the Babel instructions for creating the po/mo files - I don't believe my issue is related to the translation data... its that I don't know how to change languages... which seems like it would/should be obvious.

My debugging shows that `babel.localeselector` is not being called.  My implementation calls `refresh()`, which I think should call `babel.localeselector` (somehow... because I don't see how it works, as the `refresh()` command seems to just delete some keys from the app context... I don't know how that triggers the call to `babel.localeselector`)

```
app = Flask(__name__)
babel = Babel(app)

@babel.localeselector
def get_locale():
    # if a user is logged in, use the locale from the user settings
    user = User.get_by_id(session['user_id'])
    if user is not None: return user.lang
    return 'en'
```

and, when the user logs in, this function is called,

```
from flask_babel import refresh

def login(user_id):
    # Gets called when user successfully logs in
    refresh()
```

I have confirmed `refresh()` is being called.
But the language is not changed.

UPDATED:
Also tried this,

```
from flask import current_app
from common.models import User
from flask_babel import refresh

def login(user_id):
    # Gets called when user successfully logs in
    user = User.get_by_id(user_id)
    current_app.config['BABEL_DEFAULT_LOCALE'] = user.lang
    refresh()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the problem.  I was using,

```
import gettext
_ = gettext.gettext
```

instead of,

```
from flask_babel import gettext as _
```